# No Display Android OpenGL ES ndk

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk-r5

I am facing problem when I am trying to display an image using OpenGL ES in android ndk.
What  I am doing is reading RGB data of an bmp file of size 720x480 and trying  to display on emulator.

Application is running properly (as Logcat shows this), but I am not able to see the image on emulator display

I  have pasted my JNI code here.

Additional Information: RGB[0] is having RGB data of a BMP file.

```
                            Texture size: 1024, 512
        Frame size: 720 x 480
         Grabframe(); // functionality to draw textures 
                                Start-decoding(): // reading the RGB file (no headers)
                                 Some part of the code has been taken from:
```

http://quirkygba.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-native-coding-in-c.html

Kindly refer this link.
I will really appreciate if you could give me some pointers, so that I can proceed further.

```
#include "com_sample_GlBufferView.h";
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <GLES/glext.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define FRAME_X 1024
#define FRAME_Y 512
#define FPS_TRIGGER 5

static pthread_cond_t s_vsync_cond;
static pthread_mutex_t s_vsync_mutex;

GLuint textures[1];
GLuint textureId;

int frame_counter = 0;
time_t last_time;
int StartDecoding();
/*****************************/
    FILE *fp;
    unsigned char *RGB[No_Threads];

/******************************/
static const GLfloat vertices[] = {

    -0.5f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f
};

static const GLfloat texCoords[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f
};


static void wait_vsync()
{
       pthread_mutex_lock(&s_vsync_mutex);
       pthread_cond_wait(&s_vsync_cond, &s_vsync_mutex);
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&s_vsync_mutex);
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sample_GlBufferView_native_1start(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)

{
    /* init conditions */
    pthread_cond_init(&s_vsync_cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&s_vsync_mutex, NULL);

    while (1) {
           /* game code goes here */
            wait_vsync();
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sample_GlBufferView_native_1gl_1resize(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint w, jint h)
{
    // THIS IS CALLED WHEN CHANGING FROM PORTRAIT TO LANDSCAPE...
    // height = h;
    // width = w;}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sample_GlBufferView_native_1gl_1render(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"JNI", "native_gl_render function is called");
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //glOrthof(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    grabFrame();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    printFramesPerSecond();

    /* tell the other thread to carry on */
    pthread_cond_signal(&s_vsync_cond);
}

void printFramesPerSecond() {
    frame_counter++;
    if(time(NULL)-last_time >= FPS_TRIGGER) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"FPS #: ", "%.2f", (float)(frame_counter/(time(NULL)-last_time)));
        frame_counter = 0;
        last_time = time(NULL);
    }
}

void grabFrame() {

                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, FRAME_X, FRAME_Y, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)RGB[0]);
        }
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sample_GlBufferView_native_1init(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring filename)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"JNI", "native_init function is called");
    // TURN ON 2D TEXTURE
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glGenTextures(1, &textureId);

    // BIND THE TEXTURE
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);


    // SET TEXTURE PARAMS
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
     RGB[0]=(unsigned char *)malloc(1036900);
    //ref[thread_no]=obj1;
    StartDecoding();

}

int StartDecoding()
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"JNI", "StartDecoding function is called");
    fp=fopen("data/Image","rb");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        fread(RGB[0],1,1036800,fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

And My Android code is as follows

```
public class OpenGL_SampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private GlBufferView _glBufferview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _glBufferview = new GlBufferView(this);
        setContentView(_glBufferview);
    }
}
class GlBufferView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private String filename="/data/Tiger.mpg";
    native void native_start();
    native void native_gl_resize(int w, int h);
    native void native_gl_render();
    native void native_init(String filename);

    public GlBufferView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                native_start();
            }
        }).start();
        setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
        requestFocus();
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }

    class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        native_gl_render();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
            native_gl_resize(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
            native_init(filename);
        }
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("itv");
    }
}
```

Can anybody please tell me where is the problem in my code.

Comment: here to help you man.

Could you please eplain what you see in place of the supposed texture? Black box? Nothing at all? Glitches?

Comment: Thanks for Your reply.. I am able to see only black screen...

Comment: Still facing the same issue... Is this unique problem for me or many others are facing the same?

Comment: What is the size of your texture (pixel wise)?

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti thank you once again for reply. My texture size is 1024x512, since we can give texture width and height in power of 2. But My image size is 720x480 having 24 bit pixel values. I am not able to get where is the problem in my code.

Comment: can you post your surface initialization? I would like to see how you initialize it. Another problem could be due to multi thread, make sure you init/call the NDK functions from the same thread which initialize the surfaces.

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti I have posted my Android code also. And I am not using multithreading, I have created only single thread.

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti Here is a closely matching issue:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702873/android-ndk-opengl-es-1-0-simple-rendering

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti Can you please verify the values I have kept in Vertices[] and texCoord[]. (The Image size is 720x480). Do you think these values are proper?